# Retrieve data with relations in laravel

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, relationship

I would like to display the name of each entity in my table but it returns me

> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

My Controller

```php
$users = User::with('pearls')->latest()->get();
```

the index.blade.php

```php
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">SL No</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Email</th>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <th>{{ $user->pearls->name}}</th>
    @endforeach
    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: your question is incomplete show your db schema & you can check yourself using dd($users) whats in it, then check if pearls has a name attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this line: `{{ $user->pearls->name}}` in your blade.php

For `hasMany` relations you cant retrieve data like this.
Any relationship that has `Many` in it's name, example: `hasMany` or `belongsToMany` will always return a collection object.

Try `dd($users->pearls)`, it'll return a collection of data.
You are trying to call the property `name` on a collection object, not from a singe model.

When you're using `get()` method you will get a collection. In this case you need to iterate over it to get properties.

```
@foreach ($user->pearls as $pearl)
    {{ $pearl->name}}
@endforeach
```

By using its index you will get one of the object property

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <th>{{ $user->pearls[0]->name}}</th>
@endforeach
```

Or you can use the `first()` method instead of `get()` method in your query , so you can easily call the object property like `{{ $user->pearls->name}}` ,also you need to use `one to one` relation like `hasOne`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `pearls` is a collection, not object!
I think you've performed a one-to-many relationship between user and pearl, so, you should use foreach for pearls too:

```
foreach ($user->pearls as $pearl){
  echo $pearl->name;
}
```